# Can anyone please share the Cloud Foundry UAA repo with Maven?

Tags: maven, gradle, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, cloudfoundry-uaa

I want to build and run UAA in my local using maven not gradlew. Can anyone please help me with the repository location for UAA using Maven.

Gradle repo : https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such source repository as the developers of the UAA decided to use Gradle to build their project.

Comment: Thanks @andy-wilkinson ... But they have mentioned like to run using mvn install !!

Comment: Whatever's saying that is wrong or at least out of date. FWIW, there's no mention of `mvn` in the README.

Comment: Unfortunately links are giving wrong information. But saying question is wrong, I can't accept !!! hope every one reviewed references in https://github.com/cloudfoundry/uaa/tree/master/docs/attic